# Looking for a simple container to store uncompressed YUV video with timecode

Tags: python, ffmpeg, yuv

I have a script in python where I need to buffer 5 seconds of a YUV video stream from a camera and do some calculations on the frames before writing to disk. My issue is that I want to be able to use VFR (variable frame rate) with the video, and keep track of the timecode. I can't use resources to do much work to demux the video or decode it.
I need to use a container because I'm using pipes and ffmpeg to stream the video -- if I were to use python it seems like I'm stuck with opencv which doesn't deal with VFR

Long story short, I'm looking for a container format that stores the video in raw YUV and the timecode next to it in a simple and uncompressed way. any help with this would be much appreciated

Comment: Don't see (a simple) one in ffmpeg.

Comment: I've been looking at ts and nut

Comment: TS doesn't store rawvideo. The muxer doesn't do codec validation at present so the muxing will "succeed".

Comment: What you are looking for is NUT.